# Allow user to Expand DatagridView at runtime

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a form with two databound datagridviews, one above the other which will show different numbers of rows as the user works.

I would like to allow the user to alter the proportions of the dgv's.
So the top one would show only a few rows, and the lower one would have lots of rows visible.  Then the user could change it so he could see more of the top one and less of the bottom one.
[image: diagram showing dgvs]

I'm sorry if that's not very clear, its difficult to describe.

The dgvs are currently in a tablelayoutpanel.  I can see how to alter the proportions of the TLP but I want this to happen if the user grabs and drags a handle, but I can't see how to do that.

Comment: The SplitContainer does that

Comment: that's brilliant, thank you.  I've looked it up and it does exactly what I need. If you put it as an answer I'll accept it.